# Django - Relate model X to max n instances of Model Y

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Library management system in Django.

I have a Model `Book` in app `App1` and Model `Student` and `Employee` in `App2`. The students can issue max 3 books but employees can issue any number of books.

How can do this in django? I think I should use `ForeignKey` in `Book Model, something like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    issued_to = models.ForeignKey(Student) # <-- Student or Employee
                                           #     how do I do that?
```

But how do I make sure that max 3 `Book` instances are related to a single `Student` instance.

Comment: this is clearly a business logic. It's considered a bad idea to enforce business rules at DB level, since BL tend to change frequently and DB is not that flexible.

Comment: So I should leave the max 3 part? Ok I think that is good idea. But how do I manage that `ForeignKey` to `Student` or `Employee` thing? Should I make a common Model like `EndUser` and inherit it into `Student` and `Employee`? Any other way?

Comment: Whatever comes into your mind after reading django's docs on [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should look into django models' [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method.
It's called when you try to save an instance. For your case, the code could look like this (untested):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Person(models.Model):
    max_books = 1

    def clean(self):
        books_count = self.books.all().count()
        if books_count >= max_books:
            raise ValidationError("This person has too much books !")


 class Book(models.Model):
    issued_to = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="books")
```

This way, you can create subclass of Person model, and set your own max_books limit:

```
class Student(Person)
    max_books = 3

class Employee(Person)
    max_books = 30
```

However, be careful because, by using this solution, you will rely on django model's concrete inheritance, which can cause [performance issues](http://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/).

Comment: How about using a `pre_save` signal instead, in which you could check for the model's type to decide how many books are allowed ? Not very pythonic and probably a bit messy, but it would avoid the need for inheritance.

Comment: @astrognocci I think you're answer would work, you should submit it as answer with a code snippet to explain it.

Comment: Actually now I dropped the idea of controlling how many books can be issued. I am now focusing on how to handle the problem I described in my last comment above. Should I use `EndUser` abstract class and `GenericForeignKey` or **not** make `EndUser` abstract & use a `ForeignKey(EndUser)` in `Book`. Which would be better (and easier)?

Comment: IMHO, the easier would be concrete inheritance. Better is very subjective and depends of your needs : is database performance important for your project ? If yes, you'll have to look for something else or use third-party apps, like django-polymorphic, to optimise your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use django signals.

Django will send a `pre_save` signal before saving any model, so you can hook a function to react to it and perform your checks.

something along the lines of (building off @Agate solution):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_num_books(sender, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(sender, Student):
        max_books = 3
    elif isinstance(sender, Employee):
        max_books = 30

    books_count = sender.books.all().count()
    if books_count >= max_books:
        raise ValidationError("This person has too much books !")

pre_save.connect(validate_num_books, sender=Employee, dispatch_uid='validate_num_books')
pre_save.connect(validate_num_books, sender=Student, dispatch_uid='validate_num_books')
```

Notes:

1. I'm not sure the ValidationError will have the intended effect. Hopefully it'll be enough to bypass the model being saved, but maybe it doesn't work quite that way, or it does  in some situations or but not in others... Consider this snippet as experimental pseudo code.
2. As you might have guessed from the point above, i'm not that used to signals, and still a bit weary of those. This might be completely fine, but if a cleaner solution arises, i'd probably go for it and avoid signals entirely. Simpler is usually better.
3. The only advantage i can see of this solution over Eliot's answer is that it avoids inheritance, which, as he said, can cause performance trouble. However, if you avoid defining fields on the parent class, I *think* you should be fine.

If you decide to experiment with signals, [start here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).